# Find all possible ways to reproduce range with formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Find 14+ ways to repeat range with formulas.

- do it with a small range which has duplicates.
- each formula should start from different function.
- make formulas as short as you can.

Sample data:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Yay! | 1 |
| Wow! | 2 |
| Ah! | 3 |
| Ah! | 3 |

The desired result is the same range, repeated by formulas with the use of [built-in functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en).

I've created a [template sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vP2866RplNvcJz7ZOn-CUqVuspF_ARdBk__QSqpg79E/edit#gid=0) with all possible ways I could do it. Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

there are always more like:

```
=OFFSET(B3,,,4,2)
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(,,B3:C6))
=INDEX(IF(,,B3:C6))
=INDIRECT("R3C2:R6C3", )
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, 2)&":"&ADDRESS(6, 3))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(ROW(B3:B6), {ROW(B3:C6), B3:C6}, {2, 3}, 0))
=INDEX(TEXT(B3:C6, "@"))
={B3:B6, C3:C6}
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE({B3:C6, ROW(B3:C6)}), 9^9, 2))
```

further you go it's more questionable why would you do it that way and not the obvious easy way... e.g. one day we would need to do it for example this way due to some specific reasons:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B3:C6),,9^9)), " "))
```

but not for casual usage tho.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("R3C2:R6C3", )` is cool option, thanks!

Comment: please see my answer here. I need your expertise as I could miss something. The idea is to describe all possible functions that can produce a range, or array,

Comment: @MaxMakhrov looks great to me

Answer (score 0):

[Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vP2866RplNvcJz7ZOn-CUqVuspF_ARdBk__QSqpg79E/edit#gid=0)

## Functions to Repeat a Range

These functions can produce a range:

| # | Function | Formula Sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `{}` | `={B3:C6}` |
| 2 | `ArrayFormula`⚡<sup>1</sup> | `=ARRAYFORMULA(B3:C6)` |
| 3 | `INDEX`⚡ | `=INDEX(B3:C6)` |
| 4 | `FILTER`⚡ | `=FILTER(B3:C6,ROW(B3:B6))` |
| 5 | `SORT`⚡ | `=SORT(B3:C6,SEQUENCE(4),1)` |
| 6 | `SORTN`⚡ | `=SORTN(B3:C6,2^99,0,SEQUENCE(4),1)` |
| 7 | `QUERY` | `=QUERY(B3:C6)` |
| 8 | `OFFSET` | `=OFFSET(B3:C6,,)` |
| 9 | `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` | `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(B3:C6,4,2)` |
| 10 | `TRANSPOSE` | `=TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(B3:C6))` |
| 11 | `UNIQUE` | `=UNIQUE(B3:C6,1)` |
| 12 | `INDIRECT` | `=INDIRECT("B3:C6")` |
| 13 | `IMPORTRANGE` | `=IMPORTRANGE(SS_ID,"Sheet1!B3:C6")` |
| 14 | `IMPORTDATA` | `=IMPORTDATA(CSV_URL)` |
|  |  |  |
|  | `IMPORTHTML` | `=IMPORTHTML(HTML_URL,"table",1)` |
|  | `IMPORTXML` | `=IMPORTXML(HTML_URL,"//tr[td]")` |

<sup>1</sup>⚡— ArrayFunctions. They convert expression inside into array. Sample: `=index(C3:C6*3)`

### `SS_ID`

Spreadsheet ID or URL, the first parameter for `IMPORTRANGE`

For my sample file:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vP2866RplNvcJz7ZOn-CUqVuspF_ARdBk__QSqpg79E/edit#gid=0
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Use the whole URL, or ID: `1vP2866RplNvcJz7ZOn-CUqVuspF_ARdBk__QSqpg79E`

### `CSV_URL` and `HTML_URL`

The `IMPORTDATA` function requires `.csv` data source.

`IMPORTHTML` and `IMPORTXML` require `.html` data source.

You may convert your Google Spreadsheet into both:

1. Go to `File > Share > Publish to Web`
2. Select `Web Page` or `Comma Separated Values (.csv)`
3. Select Sheet to import and proceed.
4. Add range reference to the url: `&range=B3:C6`

Sample html URL:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQSjBDAV36sy3ua2TSbLEXPsn0_h-_iUCTWKBMgUL2T8TcQt2-1X_vl0GxGlhK04BubF1phiJZQLwJa/pubhtml?gid=0&range=B3:C6&single=true`

You may [open it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQSjBDAV36sy3ua2TSbLEXPsn0_h-_iUCTWKBMgUL2T8TcQt2-1X_vl0GxGlhK04BubF1phiJZQLwJa/pubhtml?gid=0&range=B3:C6&single=true) like a usual url!

Sample csv URL:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQSjBDAV36sy3ua2TSbLEXPsn0_h-_iUCTWKBMgUL2T8TcQt2-1X_vl0GxGlhK04BubF1phiJZQLwJa/pub?gid=0&range=B3:C6&single=true&output=csv`

## Other functions

All other cases use the same finctions as descrided to reproduce a range. The first function should be always an ArrayFunction or a function that can reproduce a range.

See also:

- `RANDARRAY` - creates array of random numbers
- `SEQUENCE` - creates a sequence 1,2,3... etc.
- `FLATTEN` - gets an aray and produces the 1-column output