# Use REGEXEXTRACT() to extract only upper case letters from a sentence in Google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm thinking this should be basic but having tried a number of things I'm nowhere nearer a solution:

I have a list of names and want to extract the initials of the names in the next column:

| Name (have) | Initials (want) |
| --- | --- |
| John Wayne | JW |
| Cindy Crawford | CC |
| Björn Borg | BB |
| Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez | AOC |
| Björk | B |
| Mesut Özil | MÖ |

Note that some of these have non-English letters and they may also include hyphens. Using `REGEXMATCH()` I've been able to extract the first initial but that's where it stops working for me. For example this should work according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fE2lIk/1):

`=REGEXEXTRACT(AH2, "\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*")` but only yields the first letter.

Comment: You can use REGEXREPLACE to replace any non-capital letters with empty string and that will leave you with your desired string. Try using this `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^A-ZÀ-Ö]","")` and you can include additional character sets as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi, this works phenomenally. I just added one last block at the end to cover a few very uncommon letters from mostly nordic languages `=REGEXREPLACE(O8,"[^A-ZÀ-ÖØ-Þ]","")`. Please consider adding this as an answer for me to accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXREPLACE` to replace any non-capital letters with empty string and that will leave you with your desired string.

Try using this `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^A-ZÀ-Ö]","")` and you can include additional character sets as per your needs that you want to retain.

Here is a working screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

-edit for anyone showing up here-

Please have a look at the comment to the question. It has the best answer to this problem, by using `Regexreplace()` rather than `Regexextract()` to target anything that is *not* an upper case character and applying the relevant unicode pattern.

-/ edit -

Finally realised that RE2 (the flavour of regex used by Google sheets) doesn't support the `global` modifier and only returns the first match (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432409/multiple-regex-matches-in-google-sheets-formula)). The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43466459/6827197) to that question finds a smart workaround which allowed me to solve the problem:

`=join("",REGEXEXTRACT(AH2,REGEXREPLACE(AH2, "([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)","($1)")))`

When considering the non-English characters, I got lost in a rabbit hole [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-ascii-characters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710852/js-test-if-string-contains-any-unicode-capital) and decided that I suddenly don't care that much about international characters.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[a-z ö-]", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Although this still misses other unconventional characters, such as french accents (á, é), cedilla (ş, ç), and ß.

Comment: Really like the trick you did by using `Index()` to get the array btw. Do you have any documentation on that?

Comment: @a-burge you can add them `[a-z öşçáéß-]` and nope for the documentation - as usually, no one cared to document it. maybe see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73441747/5632629